# Pulling templates from central location

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am currently working on an automation project for my team. I am new to programming and this project has been helping me a lot understand fundamentals.

Our issue: Currently we have templates in Jupyter notebook that we use often. Whenever we want to make updates to a template we duplicate it, make changes and save.

Solution: I want to be able to call the most current template through a script, rather than having to duplicate the template every single time.

Does any anyone know if there are any modules/packages that can help me do this? 
or does anyone have experience doing anything similar? --- Again new to programming therefor my programming mindset has not yet developed.